# excel PDF printing macro not working correctly

Tags: excel, vba

This macro is not working correctly. The desired output is that automatically change the values of one cell (a list) that is formulated to change other info in the same page.
Currently is printing the whole list correctly but is not changing the info in the other cells, even tho this formulas are correct and working accordingly.

"
Sub Imprimir()
' SET UP APP -------------------
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

```
                 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                 ThisWorkbook.Activate
                
   ' INICIO -------------------
   N = Sheets("Ficha Resumen_ajustada").Range("Q1").Value
   
   For i = 1 To N
   
   Sheets("Ficha Resumen_ajustada").Range("I7").Value = Sheets("Base").Cells(8 + i, 1).Value
   
                With Worksheets("Ficha Resumen_ajustada")
                    'obj_visiibility = .Visible
                    '.Visible = xlSheetVisible
                    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                    Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "_" & CStr(Sheets("Base").Cells(8 + i, 1).Value), _
                    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                    IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
                    IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
                    OpenAfterPublish:=False
                    '.Visible = obj_visibility
                End With
                
    Next
    ' FIN -------------------
    
    ' SET UP APP -------------------
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                
                Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = True
```

End Sub
"

any idea why is this happening ?

Comment: If you turn calculation off `Application.Calculation = xlManual`, then the formulas won't update automatically.

Comment: Thanks!!! it was that simple...